# How to print out different headings on each row Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently I have some data:

```
EXAMPLE_DATA = [
    ['time', 'age', 'height', 'width', 'ethnicity', 'religion'],
    ['18:42:11', '61', '153.9615', '0.8', 'Mixed', 'None'],
    ['18:35:00', '34', '116.4253333', '10.17', 'Mixed', 'None']]
```

I have a function called 'example_func' that calls EXAMPLE_DATA[1] e.g: the 2nd row of the data

I then used the code:

```
def display_data( example_func ):

    for row in example_func:
        print(row)
```

This gives the following output:

```
18:42:11
61
153.9615
0.8
Mixed
None
```

I want the following output to be:

```
Time: 18:42:11
Age: 61
Height: 153.9615
Ethnicity: Mixed
```

However, I want to set the headings in my code, and don't want to use the headings from the EXAMPLE_DATA.

As you'll have noticed, I also don't want to display 'Width' or 'Religion' in my final output.

If you need any more information please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function that does the job:

```
def display_data(example_func):

    headings = ['Time', 'Age', 'Height', 'Ethnicity']  # Your headings
    rows = [0, 1, 2, 4]  # The corresponding rows

    for heading, row in zip(headings, rows):  # extracts each heading and the corresponding row
        print(heading + ': ' + example_func[row])
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure I understand all of your question, but here's a guess:

```
from collections import namedtuple

EXAMPLE_DATA = [
    ['time', 'age', 'height', 'width', 'ethnicity', 'religion'],
    ['18:42:11', '61', '153.9615', '0.8', 'Mixed', 'None'],
    ['18:35:00', '34', '116.4253333', '10.17', 'Mixed', 'None']]

def display_data(example_func):
    Record = namedtuple('Record', example_func[0])

    for row in example_func[1:]:
        print('Time: {time}\n'
              'Age: {age}\n'
              'Height: {height}\n'
              'Ethnicity: {ethnicity}\n'.format(**Record(*row)._asdict()))

display_data(EXAMPLE_DATA)
```

You could write it a little more concisely using [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) in  Python 3.6+.

```
def display_data(example_func):
    Record = namedtuple('Record', example_func[0])

    for rec in (Record(*row) for row in example_func[1:]):
        print(f'Time: {rec.time}\n'
              f'Age: {rec.age}\n'
              f'Height: {rec.height}\n'
              f'Ethnicity: {rec.ethnicity}\n')
```

Comment: Thank you! Everything works other than i'd like it only to display 'Time', 'Age', 'Height' and 'Ethnicity', how can i do this?

Comment: OK...give me a minute.

Answer (score 0):

use Pandas for your problem. Pandas will automatically handle the data as your requested format. you can modify the output as your wish.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: the following only works if you pass the whole table instead of one row. Oversight on my part, sorry. It's significantly more elegant this way. If you *really* want it to only work on one row, example code is at the end.

You could make a dictionary, mapping the headings you want to the index they have in `EXAMPLE_DATA`:

```
 HEADINGS = {'Time':0, 'Age':1, 'Height':2, 'Ethnicity':4}
```

With this, you can just run through the keys and display the value at the corresponding index.

```
def display_data( example_func, headings ):
    for row in example_func:
        for key in headings.keys():
            print(key + ": " + row[headings[key]]
```

However, if you want absolute efficiency, you can calculate `headings.keys()` once and just use it several times. It doesn't matter.

```
def display_data( example_func, headings ):
    keys = headings.keys()
    for row in example_func():
        for key in keys:
            print(key + ": " + row[headings[key]]
```

**One-row example code:**

```
def display_data( example_func, headings ):
    keys = headings.keys()
    for row in [example_func()]:
        for key in keys:
            print(key + ": " + row[headings[key]]
```